# innodb_lock_wait_timeout increase timeout

Tags: php, mysql, database, timeout, innodb

I am using MySQL database and trying to update records just after insert so I am getting following error `ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`.
So I decrease timeout by following query:-

```
set GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout=1
```

So my  question is:-
is it ok to do that? Will it lead to other problems  like performance issue etc.?

Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this is a web application and you are trying to hang onto the transaction from one page to the next, *don't*; it won't work.

What do you mean by "just after"?  If you are doing nothing between the two statements, even a timeout of 1 second should be big enough.

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1;
mysql> SELECT @@innodb_lock_wait_timeout;
+----------------------------+
| @@innodb_lock_wait_timeout |
+----------------------------+
|                         50 |
+----------------------------+
mysql> SET SESSION innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1;
mysql> SELECT @@innodb_lock_wait_timeout;
+----------------------------+
| @@innodb_lock_wait_timeout |
+----------------------------+
|                          1 |
+----------------------------+
```

To explain GLOBAL vs SESSION for VARIABLES:  The GLOBAL value is used to *initialize* the SESSION value when your connection starts.  After that, you can change the SESSION value to affect what you are doing.  And changing the GLOBAL value has no effect on your *current* connection.

Changing the timeout to 1 is quite safe (once you understand GLOBAL vs SESSION).  The only thing that will change is the frequency of getting that error.

Comment: At least for me on MySQL 5.6 it did not work out:

```mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@innodb_lock_wait_timeout;
+----------------------------+
| @@innodb_lock_wait_timeout |
+----------------------------+
|                         50 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @AinTohvri - Note `GLOBAL` versus `SESSION`.

Comment: I change both variables to 1 and it still takes 50s for the 2nd tx to timeout while the 1st tx locks the same row in table. Would you please explain why "If this is a web application and you are trying to hang onto the transaction from one page to the next, don't; it won't work." ? Thanks @RickJames

Comment: @David - Web servers start fresh with each invocation.  Nothing can be saved from one page to the next unless you save it outside.  Places to save info:   files, cookies, database.  The database transaction goes away when the connection goes away.  And the connection goes away when the web page terminates.

Comment: This does not explain the long timeout. Expectation: LockTimeout=1; try to get lock that's acquired already; wait 1s; fail. Reality: it waits much longer before timeout.

Comment: @TomášFejfar - Please start a new Question with your specifics.  Please include the code inside the transactions, when and where timeouts are set, etc.  (I'm worried that we are not seeing a subtle difference between this Question and your situation.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72915956/innodb-lock-wait-timeout-timeout-is-ignored